# Integral involving integration by parts

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I have the following integral where the negative exponent on natural e is making me question my approach.

Problem:

\begin{eqnarray*}
\int_0^{\infty} x^3e^{-x} dx.
\end{eqnarray*}

My approach so far:

- I am assuming I am to use $u$-sub or integration by parts.
- I have $u = -x$
- I end up getting to $u^3e^u-\int3u^2e^u\,du$

I am stuck here. Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Also, a confirmation of my approach would be helpful. Am I missing any technique due to the negative exponent?

Comment: You approach will work.  You just have to do integration by parts two more times.  I think most people wouldn't have bothered with the $u$-substitution.

Comment: Keep integrating by parts until the $x^3$ differentiates to $6$.

Comment: Hm so I would have to integrate by parts a total of 3 times?

Comment: @jackbenimbo Yes, that's correct.

Comment: I would use the by-parts shortcut of tabular integration (also known as the "Stand and Deliver" method, because it showed up in that movie.

Comment: This should make the math in your question much easier for you and everyone else to read: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Thank you Robert! I had no idea this was available. This way I can make them more clear in the future, no doubt. Appreciate it.

Comment: Happy to help! ${}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\int x^3e^{-x}dx=-x^3e^{-x}+\int3x^2e^{-x}dx=-x^3e^{-x}-3x^2e^{-x}+6\int xe^{-x}dx=$$
$$=-x^3e^{-x}-3x^2e^{-x}-6xe^{-x}+6\int e^{-x}dx=-x^3e^{-x}-3x^2e^{-x}-6xe^{-x}-6e^{-x}+C.$$
Can you end it now?

I got the answer: $6$.

Comment: You are welcome! The integration by parts forever!

Answer (score 2):

The direct way to do this is to integrate by parts 3 times.  Each time reducing the exponent of $x$ by $1$

A little sneaker is to say let $I_n = \int_0^\infty x^n e^{-x}\ dx$ then by integration by parts show that $I_{n+1} = (n+1)I_n,$ therefore $I_n = n!\int_0^{\infty} e^{-x}\ dx = n!.$

If you hate integration by parts, you can use differentiation under the integral sign, aka "Feynman's trick"

let $f(s) = \int_0^\infty e^{-sx} \ dx = \frac {1}{s}$

$\frac {d}{ds} f(s) = \int_0^\infty \frac {d}{ds} e^{-sx} \ dx = \int_0^\infty -xe^{-sx} \ dx = \frac {d}{ds} \frac {1}{s} = - s^{-2}\\
\frac {d^n}{ds^n} f(s) = \int_0^\infty (-1)^nx^ne^{-sx} \ dx = (-1)^n n! s^{-(n+1)}$

Evaluate at $s= 1$

$\int_0^\infty x^ne^{-x} \ dx  = n!$

And eventually you will learn about the $\Gamma$ function and the Laplace Transform...

Comment: Thank you for your contribution! Is this something we learn in Calc II (Early Transcendantals - briggs text) or perhaps later in Vector Calc..?

Comment: It really depends on your instructor and what they think is important.  There are many "integration tricks" which do not require any more theoretical underpinning than you already have, but which an instruct may not think is worth the time do discuss.

Answer (score 1):

Using the substitution $x=-\log y$ the integral $I= \int_0^\infty x^3 \; e^{-x} \, dx$ transforms to
$$I=-\int_0^1 \; (\log y)^3 \; dy$$
However the most obvious route to evaluating this integral still requires integration by parts 3 times plus a lot of additional algebra

The integral of $(\log x)^3$ in terms of the integral of $(\log x)^2$
$$\int (\log x)^3 \,dx=\log x \int (\log x)^2 \,dx\,-\int \frac{1}{x} \, \int (\log x)^2 \, dx \,dx\tag{1}$$
The integral of $(\log x)^2$ in terms of the integral of $\log x$
$$\int (\log x)^2 \,dx=\log x \int \log x \,dx\,-\int \frac{1}{x} \, \int \log x \, dx \,dx\tag{2}$$
The integral of $\log x$ in terms of the integral of $1$
$$\int \log x \,dx=\log x\int\,1\,dx-\int \frac{1}{x}\int\,1\,dx\,dx=x \log x -x\tag{3}$$

The full calculation is made in this question [Integral of $(\log x)^3$ (Spivak's Calculus, Chapter 19, Problem 3v)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1044819/integral-of-log-x3-spivaks-calculus-chapter-19-problem-3v) plus answers along the lines already investigated.

Answer (score 1):

One more method (when you don't want to do multiple IBP):
$$\int x^3e^{-x} dx=C_1x^3e^{-x}+C_2x^2e^{-x}+C_3xe^{-x}+C_4e^{-x}+C_5 \iff \\
(C_1x^3e^{-x}+C_2x^2e^{-x}+C_3xe^{-x}+C_4e^{-x}+C_5)'=x^3e^{-x} \iff \\
\color{green}{3C_1x^2e^{-x}}-\color{red}{C_1x^3e^{-x}}+\color{blue}{2C_2xe^{-x}}-\color{green}{C_2x^2e^{-x}}+\color{brown}{C_3e^{-x}}-\color{blue}{C_3xe^{-x}}-\color{brown}{C_4e^{-x}}=x^3e^{-x} \iff \\
\begin{cases}\color{red}{-C_1}=1\\ 
\color{green}{3C_1-C_2}=0\\
\color{blue}{2C_2-C_3}=0\\
\color{brown}{C_3-C_4}=0\end{cases} \Rightarrow C_1=-1,C_2=-3,C_3=-6, C_4=-6.\\
$$

Answer (score 1):

$$I=\int_0^{\infty}x^3e^{-x}dx$$
There are two main ways we can approach this, firstly is the gamma function. It  is known that:
$$n!=\Gamma(n+1)=\int_0^{\infty}x^ne^{-x}dx$$
$$\therefore\,I=\Gamma(4)=3!=6$$
The second way is indeed integration by parts. To recap:
$$\int u\frac{dv}{dx}dx=uv-\int v\frac{du}{dx}dx$$
Firstly for our integral it may be easier to make a substitution to remove the minus sign to avoid confusion:
$$I=\int_0^{\infty}x^3e^{-x}dx$$
$w=-x\,,dx=-dw$
$$\therefore\,I=\int_0^{-\infty}w^3e^wdw=\left[w^3e^w\right]_0^{-\infty}-3\int_0^{-\infty}w^2e^wdw=-3\left(\left[w^2e^w\right]_0^{-\infty}-2\int_0^{-\infty}we^wdw\right)=6\int_0^{-\infty}we^wdw=6\left(\left[we^w\right]_0^{-\infty}-\int_0^{-\infty}e^wdw\right)=-6\int_0^{-\infty}e^wdw=6\int_{-\infty}^0e^wdw=6\left[e^w\right]_{-\infty}^0=6(1-0)=6$$

Comment: Thanks you for your clear approach, Henry. I appreciate you taking the time.